# xcode build command line variables cannot be passed to both UI tests and App

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I run the following command from Terminal:

```
xcodebuild test-without-building \
-workspace 'MyProject.xcworkspace' \
-scheme 'QA Automation' \
-destination 'OS=11.0,name=iPhone 6' \
-derivedDataPath /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData \
-only-testing:UITesting/testA \
WIREMOCK_PORT='9090'
```

In my XCTest code I can access WIREMOCK_PORT as follows:

```
var port = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["WIREMOCK_PORT"]!
```

I can then launch the app passing the value as follows:

```
app.launchEnvironment = ["WIREMOCK_PORT": port]
app.launch()
```

However the app does not have access to WIREMOCK_PORT because I had to untick "Use the Run action's arguments and environment variables" under Edit Scheme in order for my command line environment variable to be recognised.

Question: How can I pass a command line variable to both the XCTest and the target app?

Context:
The CI server will run multiple iOS simulators and multiple Wiremock servers. Each simulator will execute a single test class at a time. I will build the app once (xcodebuild build-for-testing) and the simulators will use this one build with the environment variable.  The test needs the port to manage the mock server and point the app to the correct mock server.

Answer (score 4):

If i understand your question correctly it might help:

You can pass the command line variable to XCTest and App by modifying your `scheme.xcscheme` file which can found by exploring the package content of `.xcodeproj` under `xcshareddata`.

A custom python script can modify `scheme.xcscheme` right before you run `xcodebuild` command and add environment variable in below mentioned format. Then app is configured for testing on the port you want.

`<CommandLineArgument
    argument = "-WIREMOCK_PORT"
    isEnabled = "YES">
</CommandLineArgument>`

Add your LaunchArgs or Env Variables in above format to `.xcscheme` file.

Comment: It is same but if you need to prepare your app from CI with a different configuration, like adding new Launch arg or enable one then it is helpful, especially if your project has multiple test target and you want to test any one of those.

Answer (score 0):

Could you instead pass the port as a `launchArgument` rather than an environment variable?

```
app.launchArguments.append("--WIREMOCK_PORT=\(port)"
app.launch()
```

---

And in your app:

```
let argument = ProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments.filter({ $0.hasPrefix("--WIREMOCK_PORT=") }).first
let port = argument?.components(separatedBy: "=").last
```

Comment: I don't think it will make a difference - whether I use an environment variable or an argument.  I ended up naming the simulator as "iPhone6_9090" and using SIMULATOR_DEVICE_NAME which is accessible from both the test and app code. Then took the last 4 characters as the port.

Comment: How to get SIMULATOR_DEVICE_NAME?

Comment: Run `instruments -s devices` to list all available devices